# How can I access the OpenDaylight Northbound REST API

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to use OpenDaylight to communicate with network devices speaking NETCONF.

I have the newest release (NEON) with all NETCONF and RESTCONF features installed. I have tried several ways to access the northbound RESTCONF API. Unfortunately, neither dlux nor apiexplorer seem to work in the newest release.

When I try to access http://localhost:8181/apidoc/explorer or use restconf from APIs of former releases, I get 404 errors.

I am positive that ODL and restconf is running correctly, for I receive answers to my postman GET requests like

```
<errors xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf">
    <error>
        <error-type>protocol</error-type>
        <error-tag>data-missing</error-tag>
        <error-message>Mount point does not exist.</error-message>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link http://localhost:8181/apidoc/explorer/index.html did the trick. I just had to add the "index.html" at the end. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

correct, the GUI frontends like dlux are no longer maintained or released with
OpenDaylight.

The GET response you show is working and telling you that the device you
are trying to retrieve does not exist. Is it mounted? What is the full
GET URL you are using?

here's one that works in a test environment I'm using:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://$ODL_SYSTEM_IP:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/$DEV_TYPE-netconf-scaling-device-10
```

but, note that $DEV_TYPE-netconf-scaling-device-10 is already mounted.

Comment: Your GET URL does not work in my setup, since I have not mounted the device yet. I also read that the dlux is not functional in newer releases. But it seems like the API explorer still works in Neon, as I wrote in my answer.